# Why is my "multiple background" feature implementation of css3 not working?

Tags: html, css

I saw this article: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ and I try to add a noise image to a background image so that the noise overlaps the background.
This is my css code:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed, url(../img/bgnoise_lg_dark.png) repeat scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But actually only the background image is shown without the noise.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to swap the image order.  The topmost layer goes first and the bottom most layer goes last.  I would guess your background image layer is covering up your noise layer.

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bgnoise_lg_dark.png) repeat scroll, url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hm, okay now is the noise on top, but the the noise is not transparent like it should be and stretched over the whole screen :/

Comment: Not sure.  You might try splitting the values out: i.e. make background-image, background-repeat and background-position separate lines.  It should work either way, but there may be something else you spot trying it.